# Entity Frameworks 4 - Changing the model does not update the T4 self tracking template files

Tags: entity-framework-4, t4, self-tracking-entities

I am using self tracking entities and have moved the entity classes to another assembly by using 'Add as link' to point to the TT file as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/pages/feature-ctp-walkthrough-self-tracking-entities-for-the-entity-framework.aspx).  Now though, when I update the model (for instance change a property name) the template is not automatically run and so the entity class does not get updated.

I can of course manually run the template to get the updates, but it would be easier if it ran automatically in the way it did before I moved the classes.  Is there any way to achieve this?

Darren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not done this but I suspect the following is possible. Mark the model with a custom tool (see under properties of the file in solution explorer). Then create a small program (see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customtoolsexp.aspx) for an example) that will execute a the TT's run custom tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have not run into this issue. Usually when i save the model or build the project which contains my edmx file, the code files for my entities are updated. can you share your project with me through direct email. I wouldn't mind trouble shooting the problem and then following up with team if we cant get it to work.